# Multiple errors when I try npm install

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I've cloned a git repository and am trying to run the app in the browser. The problem is that I used "npm install" and it didn't install everything, I tried npm install again and I get these errors:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler-cli@10.0.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~10.0.0" from the root 
project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^16.0.0" from @angular- 
devkit/build-angular@16.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^16.2.0" from the 
root 
project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@16.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^16.0.0" from @angular- 
devkit/build-angular@16.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^16.2.0" from the 
root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency 
resolution.
```

How do I resolve this?
I tried to use the node version the project was created on, 14.15.1, but Visual Studio Code just kept saying that this version was no longer supported and asked me to update to the latest one.

Install and uninstall node, use different versions, delete node_modules folder,

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Analise-Sensorial-app2.0",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/full-screen-image": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-page-transitions": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/photo-viewer": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta1",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.1",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.1.0",
    "cordova": "^10.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "9.0.0",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.2.2",
    "platform": "1.3.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1002.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "3.2.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": "^1.2.5",
    "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions": "^0.7.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.5.8",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "es.keensoft.fullscreenimage": "^0.2.10",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
      "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": {},
      "es.keensoft.fullscreenimage": {},
      "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "browser"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the --legacy-peer-deps flag in conjunction with the --force flag

Like this:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps --force
```

You likely have packages in your package.json that rely on out of date/deprecated versions, and upgrading them would be breaking changes, so it gets stuck.

Running with legacy peer deps (legacy peer dependencies) will go through your package lock json and search for last known good versions of peer dependencies to install.

Here is a description about legacy peer deps from chat gpt:

"As of NPM version 7, peerDependencies are installed by default. The --legacy-peer-deps flag was added in npm 7 as a way to ignore peer dependencies and proceed with the installation anyway.
The --legacy-peer-deps option is generally safer and should be the preferred option when dealing with peer dependency conflicts. It ensures compatibility by falling back to older versions.
The proper way to address issues related to peer dependencies is by updating your project's dependencies to versions that are compatible with each other."

Edit: you may want to try doing this flag plus --force flag

Edit again:

After seeing your package.json, you are attempting to install angular/animations version 11 while your angular/core and common are only at 10.  You will need to either lower your animations to version 10, or update all of your core angular dependencies up to v 11 as well.

I recommend starting with making sure all of your angular packages are at level 10, like this:

```
{
  "name": "Analise-Sensorial-app2.0",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/full-screen-image": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-page-transitions": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/photo-viewer": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta1",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.1",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.1.0",
    "cordova": "^10.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "9.0.0",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.2.2",
    "platform": "1.3.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1002.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "3.2.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": "^1.2.5",
    "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions": "^0.7.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.5.8",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "es.keensoft.fullscreenimage": "^0.2.10",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
      "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": {},
      "es.keensoft.fullscreenimage": {},
      "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "browser"
    ]
  }
}
```

Then updating your angular project up to 11, 12, etc as needed, but while following their upgrade guidelines found here:

[Upgrade Angular from 10 to 11](https://update.angular.io/?v=10.0-11.0)

Comment: did not solve the problem

Comment: You may want to try both of our answers:

npm install --legacy-peer-deps --force

Comment: It appears here: 

npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

removed 1 package, and audited 1952 packages in 3s

161 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

47 vulnerabilities (2 low, 12 moderate, 23 high, 10 critical)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

Comment: That is expected, but a warning is better than an error.  You should have the packages installed and be able to run the project now

Comment: If it is still not running the application, you could try sharing your package.json file with us, that could help us determine which packages are out of sync with each other.

Comment: I edited and added the Package.json to the topic

Comment: Ok, I see the issue now, updating my answer, you are using "@angular/animations" 11 but the rest of your angular (including core) are at version 10.  You will need to bump the animations down to a 10 version or the rest of them up to 11.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try this and return later.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering is related to a dependency conflict in your Angular project's package.json file. It appears that there's a mismatch between the versions of the @angular/compiler-cli package required by different parts of your project.

Here's how you can address this issue:

**Check Your Angular Version:** The error message indicates that you're using Angular version 10 (@angular/compiler-cli@10.0.14). However, you're trying to install or use a package (@angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.0) that requires Angular version 16. This is likely the source of the conflict.
To resolve this issue, you should ensure that your project's Angular packages are all at the same version. You can update the packages with proper migration.

Or

**Use --force Flag**: you can try using the --force flag with the npm install command. However, using this flag might lead to potential issues with compatibility, so it's generally better to resolve the version conflicts manually. This will disable angular suggested protection.

```
npm install --force
```

Comment: did not solve the problem